# Recommendations for master thesis

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Let me frame my situation. At the moment, I write my master thesis (pure mathematics). According to my advisor, the content of my thesis is already "good enough".
But I still feel that the content is not adequate, especially if one wants to pursue an academic career. Until now, I carefully explained a proof of the theorem in a research paper.  Moreover, my advisor seems to be rather restrictive with improvements and recommendations, even if I directly ask him.

> So I would like to ask the Academia.SE community, if they have recommendations what a (very) good master thesis should contain.
>
> Is this question on-topic for this community?

Comment: I think that such a question would be closed as too broad.

Comment: Possibly related (not meant as self-promotion): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/59827/what-are-characteristics-of-a-good-thesis-topic

Comment: @tonysdg Thanks a lot, it was partially helpful. However, I am nearly finished with my thesis and so the problem of choosing a suitable topic is no more relevant.